# Does ASIC miners leave a trace in the mining history of bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info

I have a research interest in understanding the spread of innovation, and the adoption of ASIC machines in the Bitcoin mining community is particularly relevant.

Does ASIC machines typically leave a trace in the blocks that they mined? Would a particular type of machine leave such trace/record/identifier in the transaction record?

Answer (score 2):

No. ASICs do only hash calculation. All data in block (except nonce) is defined by pool/node software

Comment: Hi @amaclin, then if I parse the transaction history using `bitcoin-abe`, what variable (or variables) in the generated database shall contain "pool/node"-specific information? Information at the pool/node level would still be valuable observable. Thank you!

Comment: scriptSig of coinbase transaction

Comment: Or other things, like the type of payout transactions, or values in the coinbase nSequence. In general, you can only find out what pools/miners choose to reveal.